# SQL Server: Can INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tell Me When a SQL Object Was Created?

Tags: sql-server-2000, information-schema, sqlobject

Given:

- I added a non-nullable foreign key to a table.
- I settled on a way to populate the foreign key with default values.
- I checked in both changes to a re-runnable DB creation script.
- Other developers ran this script, and now they have the foreign key populated with default values on their developer machines.

A few days later however...

- I changed my mind.
- Now I'd like to populate the foreign key's default values differently.

My Question:

> Can SQL Server or INFORMATION_SCHEMA
>   tell me when SQL objects were created?

Ideally, I'd like to drop and re-add the foreign key *if* it was created before a certain date/time.

Any help or alternative strategies would be greatly appreciated.
Obviously, I'd like to avoid going to each developer's cube, asking them to drop the foreign key manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL 2000 [`sysobjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260447%28SQL.80%29.aspx) (for SQL 2000), column `crdate`

For SQL 2005+ [`sys.objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx), `create_date` and `modify_date`